Reinterpret cast of void * didn't do what I thought it would
I am trying to create a reference to a struct in an arbitrary block of memory pointed to by a void pointer.  But I cant seem to work it out!
Given the example code below (tested on clang latest), I find that my reference is initialised to the address of the void pointer itself, rather than the value of the void pointer.  Please help me understand what I dont!
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    struct Test
    {
        int a;
        void * p;
        unsigned x[10];
    };

    struct It
    {
        unsigned y[10];
    };

    Test t;
    t.p = &t.x;

    auto & s = reinterpret_cast<It &>(t.p);
    
    std::cout << std::hex << "&t=" << &t << ", &t.p=" << &t.p << ", p=" << t.p << ", s=" << (void*)&s << std::endl;
}

I get the output:
&t=0x7ffd4fbac9f8, &t.p=0x7ffd4fbaca00, p=0x7ffd4fbaca08, s=0x7ffd4fbaca00

As you can see s references memory at the address of t.p.  I was expecting the reference to be the same as the value of t.p.
To extend this further, the result is different if you change the cast line to:
auto a = t.p;
auto & s = reinterpret_cast<It &>(a);

Then you get:
&t=0x7ffc31e65578, &t.p=0x7ffc31e65580, p=0x7ffc31e65588, s=0x7ffc31e65570

Where the reference s is set to the address of t.
More of a learning question than anything but would be good to understand for the future.

What is the strict aliasing rule?

reinterpret_cast<It &>(t.p) will interpret t.p as if it was a reference, but it's a pointer. If I understand correctly, you want a reference to the thing pointed to by t.p. So you want reinterpret_cast<It &>(*t.p)

@ThreeStarProgrammer57 *t.p is invalid. You can't dereference a void pointer like that.

" I was expecting the reference to be the same as the value of t.p." the value of a reference is the value of the original object, a pointers value is the memory address of the object. Thats two totally different values. Interpreting one as the other makes no sense

@WeijunZhou you're right, I guess it would need to be reinterpret_cast<It &>(*(It*)(t.p)), which looks rather ugly. Another option is to write auto& s = *reinterpret_cast<It *>(t.p);

t.p = &t.x; since t.x is not an It, the result will be undefined behavior.  Casts from a void* pointer can be done with static_cast to another kind of pointer, but the caveat that the other thing has to be the correct type for what is being pointed to is still a requirement.

@ThreeStarProgrammer57 If you cast t.p to It* then you don't need to use reinterpret_cast when dereferencing the poiner to the same type: auto &s = *(It*)(t.p); or using static_cast instead: auto &s = *static_cast<It*>(t.p); But what Eljay said is valid, this is still UB since t.p doesn't point to an It object to begin with. You would need to change t.x to be an It object instead of an unsigned[] array. Or else use placement-new to create an It object inside the memory that t.x occupies

@RemyLebeau you're right, reinterpret_cast<It &> does nothing in my case , it can be removed. Now for the UB, if an It was constructed with a placement new inside x, it would still be UB to dereference it, right? Wouldn't it "alias" x?

@ThreeStarProgrammer57 if t.p points at t.x directly, yes. But if t.p points at the object returned by placement-new then it wouldn't be UB to cast and dereference t.p as It*.

reinterpret_cast<T &>(x) is equivalent to *reinterpret_cast<T *>(&x) (except the former doesn't respect overloaded &, which makes it useful for implementing std::addressof).
So if you had a different pointer type that can be dereferenced, you could do reinterpret_cast<It &>(*t.p). But since void * can't be dereferenced, your only option is *reinterpret_cast<It *>(t.p).

Be good if you could add a reference to where "reinterpret_cast<T &>(x) is equivalent to *reinterpret_cast<T *>(&x)" comes from to make the answer complete.   FYI, I did just do *reinterpret_cast<It *>(t.p) in practice, but trying to do the reference thing did get me wondering!

@AshleyDuncan Done.
